# How to add table of contents to a pdf

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I have a pdf document (downloaded from SpringerLink) which has no internal table of contents (the sort that shows up in sidebars of some pdf readers, and allows you to navigate to the pages of each section).  Is there a way to add a table of contents to it?

(Apologies if this belongs in a different SE site.  Please suggest a better place to ask as appropriate.)